# pthread execution fall in infinite loop

Tags: c, pthreads, shared-memory

What i am trying is:

- created four thread(main creates 3 thread and thread 3 creates thread 4)
- one shared memory object is shared between all thread.
- another shared memory object is shared between thread two and thread four.
- Thread four waits for signal from thread 2 until shared mem obj is created.
- all are mutually exclusive.

But my program falls in infinite loop. Need help for the solution.

Below is my source code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>   /* for ftruncate */
#include <sys/mman.h> /* for shm_ and mmap */
#include <sys/stat.h> /* For mode constants */
#include <fcntl.h>    /* For O_* constants */

pthread_t T1, T2, T3, T4;

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex3 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond_one;

int fd;
int *shared_heap;
int *shared_heap2;
int *shared_heap3;
int counter = 0;

//thread one creator func
// *argv is the shared mem obj which is passed while thread is created
void* task1(void *argv) {
    int *var = (int*) argv;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    *var += 1;
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return NULL;
} 

//thread two creator func
// *argv is the shared mem obj which is passed while thread is created
void* task2(void *argv) {
    int *var = (int*) argv;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    *var += 1;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    //another mutex to create another shared mem obj
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);
    shared_heap2 = (int *) mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    assert(shared_heap2);
    counter++;
    //signal 
    if (counter > 0) {
     pthread_cond_signal(&cond_one);
        printf("signal is sent \n");
   }
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);

  return NULL;
  }

 //thread four creator func
 //created from thread three
 // *argv is the shared mem obj which is passed while thread is created
 void* task4(void *argv) {
    int *var = (int*) argv;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    *var += 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2);

    //waiting for signal from thread two
    while (counter > 0) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond_one, &mutex2);
    printf("waiting for signal. \n");
 }

    *shared_heap2 = 9;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2);


    return NULL;  
}

////thread three creator func
void* task3(void *argv) {
     int *var = (int*) argv;
     pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
     *var += 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    //thread four is create from here
     assert(pthread_create(&T4, NULL, &task4, var) == 0);
    assert(pthread_join(T4, NULL) == 0);
     return NULL;
}

int main(void) {

    pthread_cond_init(&cond_one, NULL);
     fd = shm_open("test_shared_var_heap_local", O_CREAT | O_RDWR,S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    assert(fd != -1);
    assert(ftruncate(fd, sizeof(int)) == 0);
    shared_heap = (int *) mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    assert(shared_heap);

    printf("main \n");
    //assert(shared_heap);

    assert(pthread_create(&T1, NULL, &task1, shared_heap) == 0);

    assert(pthread_create(&T2, NULL, &task2, shared_heap) == 0);

    assert(pthread_create(&T3, NULL, &task3, shared_heap) == 0);
    printf("three \n");

    assert(pthread_join(T1, NULL) == 0);
    assert(pthread_join(T3, NULL) == 0);
    assert(pthread_join(T2, NULL) == 0);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `assert()` this way.

Comment: is assert the only problem here???

Comment: No, none of your code makes any sense at all.

Comment: may i ask for some hints for this? would be grateful.

Comment: the case what i am trying is invalid or there are some problems in my source ... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But my program falls in infinite loop.

you do

```
while (counter > 0) {
  pthread_cond_wait(&cond_one, &mutex2);
  printf("waiting for signal. \n");
}
```

but *counter* is just set to 1 one time in *task2*, no reason to go out of the while

Anyway this is not the alone problem, in *task2* under *mutext2* *counter* is set to 1 and the signal is sent, so

- first possibility *task4* already finished before it was set to 1,  the signal is useless
- else *task2* is faster to run and get *mutex2* before *task4*, so when *task4* will get *mutex2* the signal was already sent, but the signal is not buffered so it will never be received by *task4*

If you want to be sure the code protected by *mutex2* in *task2* is executed before *task4* finishes the code protected by *mutex2* :

- *counter* is still initialized to 0 : `int counter = 0;`
- in *task4* when *mutex2* is get just set *counter* to 1 and remove the useless test `if (counter > 0)` to send the signal in all cases before to unlock *mutext2*
- in *task2* when *mutext2* is get replace the `while (counter > 0) {` by `if (counter == 0) {`

with that :

- if *task4* get *mutex2* before *task2* because *counter* is still 0 *task4* waits for the signal (that unlocks *mutext2*), *task2* can get *mutext2* and send the signal and unlock *mutext2* and finishes, *task4* receives the signal (that locks *mutext2*) then unlock *mutext2* and finishes
- if *task2* get *mutext2* before *task4* it sets *counter* to 1 and unlock *mutext2* and finishes, *task4* can get *mutext2* and does not wait for the signal because *counter* is 1 so  unlock *mutext2* and finishes

Comment: thanks for pointing out this in my ugly code. I will go further with this ugly code now ... :-)

Comment: @EricIpsum this is not the alone error in your code, warning

Comment: @EricIpsum _counter_ is wrongly managed to be the guard of the signal / signal waiting

Comment: what was that??

Comment: @EricIpsum I mean you set _counter_ to 1 under the _mutex2_ in _task2_, so first possibility _task'4_ already finished because _counter_ was 0 when it got the _mutext2_, else _task4_ will wait the signal *after* you send it but the signal is not buffered so it will never be received

Comment: @EricIpsum I edited my answer to add more explanation